# How can I assign elements in a row the same height?

Tags: css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, height

I got a little bootstrap problem.
I print a few elements with angular (ng repeat) and the containers adjust their height the height of the images..

[View of my recipes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AsKHu.jpg)

Code:

```
<div class="row text-center">
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-12 col-sm-12" ng-repeat="recipe in purchasedRecipes">
        <a href="{{recipe.PdfUrl}}" target="blank">
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <img src="{{recipe.ImgUrl}}" alt=""/>
                <div class="caption">
                    <h3>{{recipe.RecipeName}}</h3>
                </div>
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

The width is easy to assign with bootstrap (`class="col-lg-3 col-md-12 col-sm-12"`) How can I assign a fixed responsive height, so that my recipes are same size row for row ?

Thanks for helping :)

Comment: display:flex or display:table would do it easily . Bootsrap has a flex version that you might use : https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/utilities/flexbox/  link the library  https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css and add the  (flex) classes on the containers. --  Your example is too short to show your issue , else i would have copy/paste to make an example from it

Answer (score 0):

See [here](https://scotch.io/bar-talk/different-tricks-on-how-to-make-bootstrap-columns-all-the-same-height). Top three is:

**matchHeight.js**

- [matchHeight.js Docs](http://brm.io/jquery-match-height/)
- [matchHeight.js GitHub](https://github.com/liabru/jquery-match-height)

**Use tables**

The example that they gave:

```
@media only screen and (min-width : 768px) {
    .is-table-row {
        display: table;
    }
    .is-table-row [class*="col-"] {
        float: none;
        display: table-cell;
        vertical-align: top;
    }
}
```

**Huge negative margin and positive padding**

Their code:

```
.row.match-my-cols {
    overflow: hidden; 
}

.row.match-my-cols [class*="col-"]{
    margin-bottom: -99999px;
    padding-bottom: 99999px;
}
```

Comment: woaw , i haven't seen this CSS trick for agess (10-12 years ?) aside the selector[], thought nobody would uses it nowdays .... and that IE8 kicked away those average tricks :)